# Is it necessary to call NSManagedObjectContext save: for in-memory stores?

Tags: ios, cocoa, core-data

I'm using CoreData in my app, with a persistent store of type `NSInMemoryStoreType`.

Is it ever necessary to call `NSManagedObjectContext save:` with this type of store? Does passing `save:` to `NSManagedObjectContext` actually do *anything* for in-memory stores?

[Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/NSManagedObjectContext.html) simply states:

> **save:**
>   Attempts to commit unsaved changes to registered objects to their persistent store.

What does this actually mean in the context of an in-memory store?

Comment: +1, Very nice question. I have always saved the context believing all the objects made in the context would be moved to persistentStore and would reduce the memory footprint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I couldn't find any documentation but I am sure it is still needed.

`Core Data` has an in-memory frontend (represented by a managed object context) and a persistent backend ("store"). The persistent backend is usually a file but it can just reside inside memory for `NSInMemoryStoreType`.

For all the `Core Data` functions to work, the two parts must be separated and you push from the frontend (pending changes) to the backend (persistent data) via the `save` operation.

Note there can be several managed object contexts (frontends) for the same store (backend) and each of them has different pending changes. Note there are methods like `hasChanges` and a `NSUndoManager` on every managed object context. It still works with an in-memory store.

Some info also [here](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/220670-nsinmemorystoretype-not-really-persistent-is-it.html)

Answer (score 1):

`save:` performs validation of attributes and relationship constraints.